# Combining string an integers for the Vigenere cipher in python?

Tags: python, vigenere

I am trying to write a vigenere cipher encrypter in python. I am getting another error...

```
def vigenere(string,key):
for i in range(len(key)):
    if key[i].isupper():
        tempList = list(key)
        tempList[i] = chr(ord(key[i])-65)
        key = "".join(tempList)
    elif key[i].islower():
        tempList = list(key)
        tempList[i] = chr(ord(key[i])-97)
        key = "".join(tempList)
k = 0
newstring = ''
for i in string:
    if i.isupper():
        newstring = newstring + ((ord(i)-65)+(key[k % len(key)]))%26 + 65
    elif i.islower():
        newstring = newstring + ((ord(i)-97)+(key[k % len(key)]))%26 + 97
    k = k + 1
return newstring
```

"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" -- any help?

Comment: `((ord(i)-65)+(key[k % len(key)]))%26 + 65` adds integers to strings; that expression looks half baked.

Comment: It helps if you give us input and expected output, btw. Oh, and a **full** traceback.

Comment: `key[i] + ord(key[i])-97`; shouldn't that be `key[i] = ord(key[i])-97`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think he double checked his code before posting.  |=^/

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you  for pointing that out -- now I'm getting an error "'str' object does not support item assignment". 
As for input and output, it's a vigenere cipher, so when the input is "vigenere("aaaaaa","abc")", the output should be "abcabc". 
And could you help me the with the second for loop. How can I fix the one that adds integers to strings? What should I do instead? 
Sorry, new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***First***, you need to change:

```
key[i] + ord(key[i])-97
```

To:

```
key[i] = ord(key[i])-97
```

It seems that is a mistyping.

***Second***, the `ord(...)` function returns an int.  You want to convert it back to a char using `chr(...)`:

```
key[i] = chr(ord(key[i])-97)
```

***Finally***, in Python, strings are **immutable**.  This means you can't change the individual char of a string.  This is an easy way to do it:

```
if key[i].isupper():
    tempList = list(key)
    tempList[i] = chr(ord(key[i])-65)
    key = "".join(tempList)
elif key[i].islower():
    tempList = list(key)
    tempList[i] = chr(ord(key[i])-97)
    key = "".join(tempList)
```

Comment: Thanks! So I fixed the typo, used the "chr" function, and I set the new key to go into a new string, "keyn", and the encrypted string later on in the function to go into "newstring." Now I'm getting this error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
What does this mean, and how might I fix it? Thanks @CyberneticTwekGuruOrc

Comment: @user3342048 Your compiler should tell you what line the error happened at.  Look at that line.  It's very similar to an issue that has been resolved in this post.  Hint:  read the error message carefully and look at `ord(...)`

Comment: My compiler says that there is a problem on line 14. I think I see what you mean...I'm trying to concatenate newstring, a string, with an ASCII number and I need to turn the ASCII number into its corresponding char. 1. Is this correct? 2. How might I do this? I can't seem to find how to convert ASCII into characters, like 65 into 'A'.

Comment: @user3342048 If you want to turn a ASCII int value into a char, use the `chr(...)` function mentioned in the answer

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but I got this error message -- " unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: @user3342048 Break down that one line and find there you attempt to add a string (str) and int.  You can't add them together.  Strings use `+` for concatenation (putting strings together) strings.  Ints use `+` for addition.   So you can't do string + int

Comment: @CiberneticTwerkGuruOrc Yeah, I did, and I added the chr() function, but it didn't work. When I added the chr function, it looked like this:
newstring = newstring + chr(((ord(i)-65)+(key[k % len(key)]))%26 + 65)
Did I implement it incorrectly? And thanks so, so much.

Comment: `key[k % len(key)]` this part will create a char (or string).  Make sure you first make it a int (use `ord` function) before trying to do addition.  So something like:  `newstring = newstring + chr(((ord(i)-65)+(ord(key[k % len(key)])))%26 + 65)`

Comment: Oh, I see - that makes complete sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3342048  No problem.  Glad I can help.  Also, if you found this answer to be correct, please mark it as so:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work